# Deleting nodes from a binary tree in c

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

The issue arises when a node which is not available in the tree is given to be deleted.It works perfectly when an integer which is available in the tree is given to be deleted.Help much appreciated.

```
int delNode(struct node* ptr,int item)
{   struct node* y;

if(!ptr)
    return 0;
if(item==ptr->left->data){
    y=ptr->left;
    ptr->left=NULL;
    free(y);}
else if(item==ptr->right->data){
    y=ptr->right;
    ptr->right=NULL;
    free(y);}
else if(item>ptr->data)
    delNode(ptr->right,item);
else    
    delNode(ptr->left,item);    

}

void main()
{
struct node* treeNode;
treeNode=NULL;
addItem(&treeNode,5);
addItem(&treeNode,3);
addItem(&treeNode,2);
addItem(&treeNode,4);
addItem(&treeNode,8);
addItem(&treeNode,7);
addItem(&treeNode,9);
preorder(treeNode);
search(treeNode,9)?printf("Found"):printf("Not Found");
delNode(treeNode,9);
preorder(treeNode);
//printf("Depth:%i",depth(treeNode));
}
```

Comment: What is "the issue"? You've only described when it happens, not what happens.

Comment: The code is missing the struct node definition.

Comment: the delnode function has a major logic fault.  It effectively deletes whole sub trees rather than just the current node.  suggest drawing a picture of (say) 5 'balanced' nodes and they look at what needs to be accomplished to remove the center node.  what needs to be done to remove a leaf node, etc

Comment: struct node{
 int data;
 struct node* right;
 struct node* left;
     };